# Getting future duration_in_traffic from Google Distance Matrix

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I am calling the Google distance matrix api with an API key along with a Unix time that is three weeks in the future.  My goal is to get duration_in_traffic for a typical weekday at a couple of different times of day.

My issue is that I am getting "duration_in_traffic" times that do not differ from "duration" times in the same return.

I am pretty certain that I am getting the UTC right with respect to local time but, just in case, I varied the time with no variation in the result.

What I have been able to find in my searches hints to me that there is a way to get what I am after but that I may have to change the type of account that I have with Google.  Although I am using the account on a 30 day free trial I did "enable billing" in case that was the problem.  No luck so far.  Does anyone out there know the solution I need?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!